# Is SYSDATE officially supported on db2?

Tags: oracle, db2, sysdate

It appears that SYSDATE (as in Oracle) works on Db2 even with non-Oracle compliant setting - default, DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR is not set to ORA.

Only kind of official info I could find is on:https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/236545

> From DB2 9.7 onwards, SYSDATE has been marked as a keyword which is a
>   special register as synonym for CURRENT TIMESTAMP(0) or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0).‚

Background of the question: need my scripts to work both on Oracle and Db2.

Do I need Db2 flavored scripts or can just use SYSDATE for both?

Is there a link to official documentation of the fact?

EDIT:
As per comment from @data_henrik

I agree that documentation states

> SYSDATE can also be specified as a synonym for CURRENT TIMESTAMP(0).

But this is just CAN. It does not state it IS.

EDIT 2:

It seems I was reading documentation wrong. Thanks @data_henrik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here the documentation on [CURRENT TIMESTAMP in Db2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005886.html). It states:

> SYSDATE can also be specified as a synonym for CURRENT TIMESTAMP(0).

It is part of the official Db2 documentation and it has been in there for many releases. You can find it using "search"... ;-).

Comment: SYSDATE is a synonym for CURRENT TIMESTAMP when Db2-server is running on Linux/Unix/Windows,  or on Z/OS.  But this may not be the case for Db2-for-i (as/400).

Comment: @data_henrik I did find that page, but the statement on the very link you provided is  _On the link provided SYSDATE can also be specified as a synonym for CURRENT TIMESTAMP(0)._ So it CAN (and, apparently, it IS), but I can't see documentation stating it IS, so I don't have to worry about various implementations and versions.

Comment: "It can be specified as..." means that you don't need to use it, you can stick with CURRENT TIMESTAMP (Db2 syntax). But if you are in the mood for it or sympathize with Oracle syntax or you need to use it for compatibility, then, yes, then you CAN use it.